# Why some questions are unanswered yet?

Tags: discussion, soft-question, unanswered-questions

I am not new here. Well... I see here some questions in "unanswered" category that have gained many votes but are unanswered yet. As far as I know, the site has many outspoken members viz., some them are mathematicians, engineers etc. So how is it possible that no answer is given yet? Do these questions need research work? Are they just new in field of mathematics? Or, people ignore it? Or answers are being found?

Comment: There are a lot of problems in mathematics to which no (satisfactory) answer has been given (in general, not just on the site). Consequently, sometimes, people post beautiful questions and discover that no one here has any idea (which could likely be an indication that no one elsewhere has any idea either).

Comment: It's often a case that the question is good, but it's hard to answer. Also, I think the question may not be posted at a right time; people know the answer don't have a chance to look at it. However, Stach Exchange doesn't allow duplication, so it remains unanswered.

Comment: Approximately 590 questions are posted *every day* on the website. It's very difficult to keep up with that rate. The bright side is that 79% of all questions have been answered so far, which isn't too shabby.

Comment: Some people put their answers in the Comment space, to protest the reputation system...

Comment: But there are questions in unanswered category which can easily be seen and have many views. But they have not any answer. Even one question is with 107k views

Comment: On @GEdgar  reamrk: whoever feels like doing so, please stop, and post CW answers instead.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+views%3A100000 shows there are only seven questions with more than 100k views. All of which have several voted answers.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358423/a-short-proof-for-dimrt-dimr1 What about this? 6K views is a big deal. Isn't it Asaf Karagila?

Comment: Did you notice that this question was also asked on MathOverflow, received a lot of attention, and still wasn't answered? Some questions are just difficult...

Comment: Even difficult for Mathematicians on this site?

Comment: Well, from 107K to 6K there's over 100K views drop. I agree it's a big deal. But it can be insanely easy to ask very difficult questions. As I once wrote on this site (I believe the associated question was deleted later), the trick is not to ask hard questions, it is to ask natural questions which will both propel research forward and will have an answer. This is why I am not impressed by open problems in number theory either. It's easy to toss a stone into the well, the trick is to be able to get it out as well.

Comment: It is simply a matter of cherry picking. People at this site will either go for the interesting stuff, posted by their fellow-mathematicians, or for the trivial stuff, posted by high school students. If you post something in-between, which is considered uninteresting but not so trivial that it can be answered on the auto-pilot, it will usually be ignored.